# How to get a directory creation date in java?

Tags: java, date, directory, creation

I need help getting the creation data of a folder, i try with this method

```
Path p = Paths.get(folderRoute);
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(p,  BasicFileAttributes.class);
FileTime a= attr.creationTime();
```

but i keep getting a error of file not found, please help

Comment: Which line is giving you file not found?

Comment: BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(p,  BasicFileAttributes.class);

Comment: Are you sure that folderRoute is the correct URI for the file?

Comment: What does `System.out.println(Files.exists(p));` display?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your path to desired directory in a string, for instance **folder**

```
URI folderRoute = new File(folder).toURI();
Path p = Paths.get(folderRoute);
BasicFileAttributes attr = null;
try {
    attr = Files.readAttributes(p,  BasicFileAttributes.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
    FileTime a = attr.creationTime();
    System.out.println(a.toString());
```

Comment: This just converts the path to a URI and back to a Path again, then does the same things the original question does.  How does that increase the likelihood of obtaining the creation time?